# Weird output when I copy script from sublime to shell but works fine when I copy line by line

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

Below is a script I wrote in a sublime

```
DAY="$(ls -ltr 1000011.AUD | awk '{print $6,$7}')"
if [ $(ls -ltr *.AUD | egrep "$DAY" | wc -l) -gt 0 ]
then 
    if [ $(ls -ltr *.AUD | egrep "$DAY" | wc -l) -gt 1 ]
    then 
        echo "More files are there"
    else
        echo "Everything Ok"
        FNAME="$(ls -ltr *.AUD | egrep "$DAY" | awk -F ' ' '{print $9}')"
        #DAY="$(date +%m%d%Y)"
        #less "$FNAME" |  grep "$DAY" | grep 'from' | awk -F' ' '{print $7}' | sort | uniq -c
    fi
else
    echo "Send alarm"
fi
```

but when I copy full script it shows some weird output as shown in the attached screenshot (but it works fine when I copy line by line).
[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnMu2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably indented your script with tabs. For some terminals, a copy pasted tab is the same as pressing tab directly. Pressing tab enables command completion, that's what you see here.

Possible solutions:

- **Recommended**: Don't copy paste code to the terminal. Store it in a file and run that file using `chmod u+x file.sh` once and then `./file.sh` as often as you want.
- Execute `source <(cat)` then paste your script and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
- When copy-pasting, use only spaces to indent code.